# Run program.exe from eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, cmd, eclipse-plugin, runtime, exe

I am writing an eclipse-plugin witch run program.exe. I have added program.exe to plugin jar file. How can a execute this program?

```
public class Handler extends AbstractHandler {
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/*What should I write here*/);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run the program.exe from inside the plugin jar, so it needs to be extracted. In your plugin use:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("relative path to program"), null);

url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

This will find the program in the plugin jar and extract it to a temporary location (done by `FileLocator.toFileURL`).

Answer (score 0):

You should just execute the program like you would in cmd, but now specify the whole path of the programs location.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\your\\path\\program.exe");
```

In the Oracle documentation of the [Runtime class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) you can see the acceptable inputs in `exec()`.

Comment: I am searching some way to do not use hard coded string. I need run program which is provided with plugin and is located in jar file.