# Supplying executables with Eclipse plugin while exporting

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse plugin, which uses an executable file for performing certain tasks. Until now, I had the executable reside in some folder on my system. Now that I am exporting the plugin, I need to supply the executables as well, and run them on different machines.

A bit of research tells me that I should make an additional folder inside the plugin project, and put the executable within it. Then, some code will extract the executable to a temporary location when the plugin is run. Following the advice, I made an additional folder named "executables", and put my executables inside it. I am trying to use the following code, copied from SO itself:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("relative path to program"), null);
url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

This code was provided by **greg-449**, in response to this question:[Run program.exe from eclipse plugin project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068876/run-program-exe-from-eclipse-plugin-project)

Regarding the above code, I want to know the following things:

1. What is plugin id? Is it the id displayed on the overview page of the plugin manifest file?
2. What is "relative path of program"? In my case, should it be /executables/program.o?

Following the above steps, and then installing the plugin in Eclipse, gives me **unhandled loop exception** when I try to run the command.

Here is the program:

```
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

public SampleHandler() {
}


public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("Sample");
    URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/lib/bandWidth.out"), null);
    try {
        url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(url.toString());
    return null;
}
```

}

I am just testing the above snippet with this code. The output to this was (without installing the plugin):

```
file:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/libnsight/../../../../home/limafoxtrottango/cuda-workspace/Sample/lib/bandWidth.out
```

Here is the full stack trace of the error:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:62)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:825)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:701)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:685)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:613)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Activator.getURLConverter(Activator.java:321)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:205)
at sample.handlers.SampleHandler.execute(SampleHandler.java:39)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
... 38 more
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for a more detailed message. How are you running the command? What URL are you getting from FileLocator.toFileURL

Comment: @greg-449, I have edited the question, including the full code and the output.

Comment: Well the URL looks like it is probably OK. How are you running the code, what does the .log say?

Comment: @greg-449 I have added the full stack-trace towards the end of the question. Please, have a look.

Comment: Please note that this log is generated after installing and running the plugin, and not at runtime.

Comment: At a guess FileLocator.find is not finding the file. Possibly because you haven't included the directory in your build.properties, but it could be all sorts of things.

Comment: @greg-449 I there some official way to thank a user on SO? That was exactly the problem. It now displays the correct path after installation. Thank you, sir.

Comment: I have added an answer. You can Accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin id is called `ID` on the Overview tab and `Bundle-SymbolicName` in the MANIFEST.MF

The relative path is the path relative to the root of the plugin directories.

You must list everything you want to include in the plugin in the `bin.includes` section of the `build.properties` file. You don't get an error during testing when things are missing, this only shows up when the plugin is built and installed.